Algebraic geometry interpretation for the Calabi metric on the canonical bundle of $CP^n$?
By a construction due to Calabi, there is a special Kahler (=holonomy SU(n+1)) metric in the total space of the canonical line bundle over any constant scalar curvature Kahler manifold. In particular, we can apply this construction to the canonical bundle of $CP^n$. An explicit expression for this metric(s) can be written down, but will not be needed here.
For $n=1$, the resulting metric is known as the Eguchi-Hanson gravitational instanton, and has an algebraic geometry interpretation. Consider the locus of $z_1 z_2 = z_3 z_4$ in $\mathbb{C}^4$. This complex dimension 3 surface in $\mathbb{C}^4$ has a Kahler metric induced from the flat Hermitian metric on $\mathbb{C}^4$. This surface can be further "projectivised" in two different ways, by considering the Kahler reduction on two different U(1) actions.
Taking the Kahler reduction for $$(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)\to e^{i \phi} (z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4),$$ or equivalently, projectivising $$(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)\to \lambda (z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4),\quad \lambda \in \mathbb{C},$$ gives the standard metric on $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1$. This corresponds to the standard Segre embedding of $\mathbb{P}^1\times \mathbb{P}^1\subset \mathbb{P}^3$.
Considering instead the Kahler reduction for $$(z_1, z_2, z_3, z_4)\to (e^{i\phi} z_1, e^{-i\phi} z_2, e^{i\phi} z_3, e^{-i\phi} z_4),$$ one obtains the Eguchi-Hanson instanton (=Calabi metric on the canonical bundle of $\mathbb{P}^1$). This way of thinking about the Eguchi-Hanson instanton is a re-interpretation of the standard hyper-Kahler reduction procedure of obtaining this metric.
Question: Is there a similar algebraic geometry interpretation of the Calabi metric on the total space of the canonical bundle of $\mathbb{P}^n$ for general $n$? I am in particular interested in the simplest case of $n=2$. What I want the locus of some set of polynomial relations in $\mathbb{C}^N$ of some appropriate dimension $N$, such that the Kahler metric induced on this locus from the flat metric on $\mathbb{C}^N$, Kahler reduced on some appropriate U(1) action, gives the Calabi metric.
Note: I have tried to take the Segre embedding $\mathbb{P}^1\times{\mathbb P}^2\subset \mathbb{P}^5$, which is described as the locus of 3 quadratic relations in $\mathbb{C}^6$, only two of them being independent. There are analogous U(1) actions in this case, and the corresponding Kahler reductions can be computed. In the first case one gets the standard metric on $\mathbb{P}^1\times{\mathbb P}^2$. However, in the second case one does not obtain the Calabi metric, the resulting metric is much less interesting. So, the above question still stands.
